# Загрузка картинки на сервер.

Tags: android

Хочу отправить фото из галереи.
Вот пример запроса. на который я должна отправить фото

`http:/адрес/?user_service=1&user_id=1&files[]=(здесь должно быть фото)`

Как быть и чем пользоваться. С сервера я в свою очередь получаю json-ответы.

Comment: а вы пробовали гуглом пользоваться?  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966910/androidhow-to-upload-mp3-file-to-http-server  
http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/

Comment: знаете пробовала. тогда так ошибок в коде у меня нет. и картинка не загружается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я использую для этого MultiPart

[пример здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Ты уже столько вопросов тут задала, что мне кажется, уже сама могла бы во всем разбираться

```
 /**
     * Asynchronous task to upload file to server
     */
    class UploadImageTask extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, Boolean> {

        /** Upload file to this url */
        private static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://thibault-laptop:8080/report";

        /** Send the file with this form name */
        private static final String FIELD_FILE = "file";
        private static final String FIELD_LATITUDE = "latitude";
        private static final String FIELD_LONGITUDE = "longitude";

        /**
         * Prepare activity before upload
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            mConfirm.setEnabled(false);
            mCancel.setEnabled(false);
            showDialog(UPLOAD_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        }

        /**
         * Clean app state after upload is completed
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            mConfirm.setEnabled(true);
            mDialog.dismiss();

            if (result) {
                showDialog(UPLOAD_SUCCESS_DIALOG);
            } else {
                showDialog(UPLOAD_ERROR_DIALOG);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(File... image) {
            return doFileUpload(image[0], UPLOAD_URL);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            if (values[0] == 0) {
                mDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.progress_dialog_title_uploading));
            }

            mDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
        }

        /**
         * Upload given file to given url, using raw socket
         * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966910/androidhow-to-upload-mp3-file-to-http-server
         *
         * @param file The file to upload
         * @param uploadUrl The uri the file is to be uploaded
         *
         * @return boolean true is the upload succeeded
         */
        private boolean doFileUpload(File file, String uploadUrl) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            String separator = twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd;
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int sentBytes = 0;
            long fileSize = file.length();

            // The definitive url is of the kind:
            // http://host/report/latitude,longitude
            uploadUrl += "/" + mLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mLocation.getLongitude();

            // Send request
            try {
                // Configure connection
                URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                publishProgress(0);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                // Send location params
                writeFormField(dos, separator, FIELD_LATITUDE, "" + mLocation.getLatitude());
                writeFormField(dos, separator, FIELD_LONGITUDE, "" + mLocation.getLongitude());

                // Send multipart headers
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + FIELD_FILE + "\";filename=\""
                        + file.getName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // Read file and create buffer
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Send file data
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    // Write buffer to socket
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    // Update progress dialog
                    sentBytes += bufferSize;
                    publishProgress((int)(sentBytes * 100 / fileSize));

                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot upload file: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                return false;
            }

            // Read response
            try {
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                return responseCode == 200;
            } catch (IOException ioex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Upload file failed: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
                return false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Upload file failed: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void writeFormField(DataOutputStream dos, String separator, String fieldName, String fieldValue) throws IOException
        {
            dos.writeBytes(separator);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName + "\"\r\n");
            dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
            dos.writeBytes(fieldValue);
            dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: не могла значит, пробовала я такой код. картинка не загружается и ошибок не выдаёт никаких

Comment: права на интернет есть у приложения? может сервер не принимает?