# Android, как правильно сделать сохранение картинки

Tags: java, android, сервер, bitmap

Вот я делаю приложение, где при регистрации можно добавлять аватар, как лучше всего отправлять изображение на сервер ? Сервер пишу так же. Есть идея переводить все в масив байтов и отправлять на сервер, а когда достаю данные то переводить в bitmap. Или есть другие способы ?

**UPDATE**

На сервер есть модель user, то как правильно сделать в ней поле с изображением ?

Comment: можете отправить (*кто бы мог подумать*) как обычный файл

Comment: имеете в виду, например в jpg ? Но если на сервер есть модель user, то как правильно сделать в ней поле с изображением ?

Comment: Сохраняйте изображение в папку какую-нибудь, а в модель (базу) записывайте ссылку\путь к изображению. Так вы эту же ссылку сможете передать на клиент, а он - скачать изображение.

Answer (score 2):

После гугления, нашел сразу несколько примеров, как бы это можно было сделать.

1. [Пример](http://4ybakut2004.blogspot.com/2015/07/android-upload-file-to-server.html)
2. [Пример](http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread914907.html)
3. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/222377/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)
4. [Пример](http://metanit.com/java/android/15.1.php)
5. [Пример](http://ru.androids.help/q812)

А вообще, исходя из личного опыта, это можно делать несколькими способами. Самый быстрый и простой - создавать POST запросы от клиента и отправлять их на сервер, где будет PHP код, отвечающий за сохранение необходимой картинки.
Вариант посложнее - использование сокетов. При необходимости предоставлю код из своего проекта, отвечающий за загрузку. Я делал по пятому примеру, там есть код как клиента, так и сервера.